# How to make function calculation more fast

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am using this function , its giving right output but calculation time is more , is there any way to make it more fast ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3000,size=(3000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
B=df['A']
def test(x):
   x=pd.DataFrame(x)
   averages = x.rolling(2).mean().shift(-1)  ##shift -1 series ,calculate rolling mean between two points
   averages=averages*0.02 #### multiply series by 0.02
   X3=(averages-x.values[0]*0.02).sum()
   return X3[0]

df['A']=B.rolling(200).apply(test,raw=True)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your code is trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you rewrite it to use a (3000,4) numpy array rather than a dataframe?  Without trying to understand the code in full, it looks like you could operate on the whole array at once, rather than row by row.  `mean` and `sum` take axis parameters.